# How to merge another field in object in rails json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, paperclip, rails-api

Json response which I send is like that

```
"ad": {
"id": 3,
"title": "dgdfg",
"description": "kjlj",
"video_file_name": "SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mp4",
"thumbnail_file_name": "images.jpeg",
"campaign_id": null,
"duration": null
},

"video_url": "/system/ads/videos/000/000/003/original/SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mp4?1448019186"
```

I want that video_url also merge with in ad object.

The way I send response now is

```
render json: {:success=>true, :message=>"Ad detail",:ad=>@ad, :video_url => @ad.video.url}, :status=>200
```

How I merge it with ad object?

I want to send it like

```
"ad": {
"id": 3,
"title": "dgdfg",
"description": "kjlj",
"video_file_name": "SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mp4",
"thumbnail_file_name": "images.jpeg",
"campaign_id": null,
"duration": null,
"video_url": "/system/ads/videos/000/000/003/original/SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mp4?1448019186"

 }
```

My `@ad` object is

```
#<Ad:0x007efc20495f98
id: 3,
title: "dgdfg",
description: "kjlj",
video_file_name: "SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mp4",
video_content_type: "video/mp4",
video_file_size: 1055736,
video_updated_at: Fri, 20 Nov 2015 11:33:06 UTC +00:00,
thumbnail_file_name: "images.jpeg",
thumbnail_content_type: "image/jpeg",
thumbnail_file_size: 9962,
thumbnail_updated_at: Fri, 20 Nov 2015 11:33:22 UTC +00:00,
created_at: Fri, 20 Nov 2015 11:33:22 UTC +00:00,
updated_at: Fri, 20 Nov 2015 11:33:22 UTC +00:00,
campaign_id: nil,
duration: nil>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First merge `{:video_url => @ad.video.url }` with `@ad` then do following:

```
{:ad =>  @ad.attributes.merge( :video_url => @ad.video.url )}
```

so your render call would look like following:

```
render json: {:success=>true, :message=>"Ad detail", ad:  @ad.attributes.merge( :video_url => @ad.video.url )}, :status=>200
```

You may need to use `@ad.attributes.except("created_at",....)` at following code if you don't need some of the attributes of your active record object `@ad`.

Comment: It gives an error NoMethodError: undefined method `merge' for #<Ad:0x007efc204c0568>

Comment: what is @ad? I thought it is hash!

Comment: updated my answer. you would need to use .attributes method to make object hash.

Comment: Thankuuuu :)........it works ...just one question what wrong in my question so that it down voted :(

Comment: @HaseebAhmad, just noticed you probably will need to use `@ad.attributes.except("created_at",....)` if you don't need some of the attributes of your active record object.

Answer (score 3):

Just before `render` define the object to send (note that if `@ad` is not a hash, probably it should be converted to hash before):

```
#                    ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ this depends on what @ad currently is
object_to_send = @ad.to_hash.merge(video_url: @ad.video.url)
```

and then:

```
render json: { success: true, 
               message: "Ad detail",
               ad: object_to_send }, 
       status: 200
```

Comment: It gives an error 
NoMethodError: undefined method `merge' for #<Ad:0x007efc204c0568>

Comment: Please share what class `@ad` is.

Comment: @HaseebAhmad : try use `@ad.video.path` to get the full path of the file on the filesystem

Comment: Thankuuuu :) ...just one question what wrong in my question so that it down voted :(

Comment: Ohhhh sorryyy :) If you like it will a favor for me :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `as_json` method, but you need a method that returns the URL directly

```
class Ad
  def video_url
    video.url
  end
end
```

Then in the render

```rb
render json: {
  success: true, 
  message: "Ad detail",
  ad: ad.as_json(
    only: {
      :id, :title, :description, :video_file_name, :thumbnail_file_name, :campaign_id, :duration
    },
    methods: :video_url
  ), 
  status: 200
```

of course if you want you could wrap this into some method,

```
class Ad
  def my_video_json
    as_json(
      only: {
        :id, :title, :description, :video_file_name, :thumbnail_file_name, :campaign_id, :duration
      },
      methods: :video_url
    )
  end
end
```

Then the render would look like this

```
render json: { success: true, message: "Ad detail", ad: ad.my_video_json }, status: 200
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add new key and value in hash by adding this:

```
@ad.attributes[:video_url] = @ad.video.url
```

I hope this help you.